# Secure download stream, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

This may be more of an IT question, but my organization needs to set up a download link. We have login/user security, role access and HTTPS. The entire site is completely secure.

But I've noticed in a lot of recommendations, allowing users to download usually involves some kind of

```
httpResponse.SaveToStream, Response.Transmit, etc.
```

Are these links secure as http output streams? Can this data be intercepted? If they are not secure, can you recommend a method for securing the download of data?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can obviously use SSL/TLS for point-to-point encryption, then why can't you use `[Authorize]` on your controller to ensure only certain logged in users can access?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was not clear.. We have user level security. I am not worried about the the right person clicking the link, I'm worried about the data as it comes across the web.

Comment: So your more concerned about the SSL/TLS encryption portion?

Comment: Yeah I am worried that because the output stream is only HTTP, does that mean the data could be compromised?